# unable to access spreadsheet data

Tags: python

> > > === RESTART: C:\Users\sandesh patil\Desktop\pythan_practice\quickstart.py ===
> > >       username, password:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sandesh patil\Desktop\pythan_practice\quickstart.py", line 81, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\sandesh patil\Desktop\pythan_practice\quickstart.py", line 77, in main
    print('%s, %s' % (row[0], row[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range

> > > 

- ### List item

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandas in python and access a spreadsheet as

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('/path to file.csv', engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
```